Simultaneous Diagonalization of Symmetric Matrices and Commutativity Condition



    
    
    Simultaneous Diagonalization of Symmetric Matrices


    Question: Simultaneous Diagonalization of Symmetric Matrices and Commutativity Condition

        Given two symmetric matrices A and B (both n × n), I'm trying to understand the conditions under which they can be diagonalized simultaneously. Specifically:
    

Suppose there exist real scalars α and β such that the matrix αA + βB is positive definite.
Can we conclude that A and B are simultaneously diagonalizable, meaning that there exists an invertible matrix P such that both A and B are diagonal in the same basis?

Additionally:

If A is positive definite, does there exist an invertible matrix P such that PT A P = I and PT B P is diagonal?
How does the commutativity condition AB = BA factor into this problem, and does this always hold in such cases?


        I'm trying to verify whether these conditions are sufficient for simultaneous diagonalization and the implications regarding matrix commutativity. Any insights or references to related theorems would be greatly appreciated!
    

The answer to your first question is no. $A$ and $B$ can be simultaneously diagonalized in this sense if and only if $AB=BA$. The answer to your second question is yes, regardless of whether $AB=BA$.
